# Сохранение обработанных данных на другом листе

Tags: excel, vba

Подскажите, как сохранить данные не в диапазон столбцов, а на другой лист?

```
Sub copyTable()
Dim colRange(), destColRange()
Dim Text As String
Dim i As Long, newI As Long, n As Long, j As Long
Dim maxLen As Long
colRange = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 'Columns where your data is'
destColRange = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17) 'Columns where you want
'data be copied'
n = UBound(colRange) - LBound(colRange)-1
i = 2 'Initial row'
newI = i
maxLen = 500 'Maximum size allowed in one cell'

While Not (Cells(i, colRange(0)) Is Nothing) And (Cells(i, colRange(0)) <> 
"")
    Text = Cells(i, colRange(n))

    Do
        For j = 0 To n - 1
            Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Cells(i, colRange(j))
        Next j

        Cells(newI, destColRange(j)) = Mid(Text, 1, maxLen)
        Text = Mid(Text, maxLen + 1)
        newI = newI + 1
    Loop Until Len(Text) <= 0

    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с объектами листа медленная. Переписал. Обработка в массивах. Добавлено копирование заголовков, определение размера диапазона данных.

```
Sub copyTable2()
Const lClmn As Long = 5 ' проверяемый столбец'
Const lMaxLen As Long = 20 ' допустимая длина текста'
Dim aData()
Dim sTxt As String
Dim lRw As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long, j As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub ' только шапка, данных нет'
        aData = .Range("A1:G" & lRw).Value ' данные в массив'
    End With

    For i = 2 To lRw
        ' определяем макс. возможное количество строк массива выгрузки'
        k = k + Int(Len(aData(i, lClmn)) / lMaxLen) + 1
    Next i

    ReDim aRes(1 To k, 1 To UBound(aData, 2)) ' задаем размерность масива выгрузки'
    k = 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2): aRes(1, j) = aData(1, j): Next j ' копируем заголовки'

    For i = 2 To lRw
        If aData(i, 1) <> "" Then ' если в первом столбце не пусто'
            Do ' цикл, пока не выберем весь текст'
                k = k + 1

                For j = 1 To UBound(aData, 2)
                    aRes(k, j) = aData(i, j) ' копируем строку'
                Next j

                aRes(k, lClmn) = Left$(aData(i, lClmn), lMaxLen) ' часть текста в проверяемый столбец'
                aData(i, lClmn) = Mid$(aData(i, lClmn), lMaxLen + 1) ' обрезаем проверяемый текст'
            Loop While Len(aData(i, lClmn)) > 0 ' условие цикла - пока есть текст'
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Лист3") ' лист для выгрузки'
        .UsedRange.Delete ' чистим лист перед выгрузкой'
        .Range("A1:G" & k).Value = aRes ' выгружаем результат на лист'
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.